# How to add Spine animation to Phaser game?

Tags: javascript, animation, phaser-framework, pixi.js

I am new to Phaser and the whole javascript games, and I am trying to add Spine animation to Phaser. Is there a way to do that?
I also tried to play my animation using Pixi.js and it worked. 
Also I know that Phaser is built on top of Pixi, can access Pixi directly from Phaser or I have to add both libraries into my project and use Pixi for Spine animation and use Phaser for other tasks?
Any code samples would be very helpful.

Comment: Have you managed to come up with something since you posted your question? Would be great if you share your example if you got it working.

Comment: Hi Nikola, my solution was not to use spine animation and convert my animation to other format supported by Phaser. Because it seems that Phaser developers did not add spine support to Phaser for some strong reasons. So just convert the animations into other format and move one. Good luck.

Comment: http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/13858-phaser-spine/

Answer (score 0):

Old but just in case someone is looking, you should try to add https://github.com/pixijs/pixi-spine

Not using Phaser but an other engine using PIXI to for rendering and I made it work, same for all "PIXI plugins".